Autocompleting attribute field in Drag and Drop Designer in QGIS
I need to manually add some rather long attributes to features. Is there a way to have the Drag and Drop Designer auto-complete these? (I access the table with 'Modify all selected features simultaneously')
Example: I start writing 'rho' and it suggests 'rhododendron'

You could predefine a list of attributes and choose from it.

Setting the edit widget type to "Unique Values" AND editable option do exactly that...
